# ImageData of an image section

Tags: image-processing, geometry

How can I take the image data of the area around a max?

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDCGF.png"]
markers = MaxDetect[GaussianFilter[img, 10], Padding -> 1]; 
HighlightImage[img, markers, Method -> {"DiskMarkers", 5}]
```

[image]

[image: image with marker]

I would like to take the image data of the shape it is within like:

[image: image with border]

Update: I made a brute force version using `ImageTrim[]` and `PixelValuePositions[]` but this is just using a approximate square around the max detect point

Comment: I don’t understand how the boundary of the region is determined.

Comment: @C.E. It is just a freehand example of the region I would like to detect

Comment: If it is not part of the question how to compute it, please provide it so we have an example region to work with in the form that you have it. Otherwise it can easily happen that we write an answer using an example region but then you have a problem applying this to your problem because your region is expressed in a different way. If it is part of the question how to compute the region, please describe how the region is supposed to be computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand exactly what is required but I'll try something. In the last image all pixels are set to 0 except in the areas of interest (where the pixels of the original image are shown).

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDCGF.png"]
markers = MaxDetect[GaussianFilter[img, 10], 0.03, Padding -> 1]
comp = ImageMultiply[img, markers]
data = ImageData[comp];
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can keep track of CompenentMeasurements from picture to picture? For exammple if the next picture there is another spot to the left, the identifier will shift 1,2,3?